# sscanf() causes link to fail when powl() is present

Tags: c, scanf, pow

When I compile the pared-down program below, I get the following error from the linker:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -O3 powltest.c -o powltest
/tmp/ccYkWTGI.o: In function `main':
powltest.c:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `powl'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I comment out the line with `sscanf()`, the compile is successful and the program runs correctly given the reduced functionality. It also works if I instead comment out the line containing `powl()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int bits = 5;
    unsigned int n = 0;
    unsigned long long start = 0;

    n = sscanf(argv[1], "%u", &bits);
    printf("%u\n", bits);
    start = powl(2, bits) - 1;
    printf("%llu\n", start);
}
```

Here are the versions:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu9) 4.4.1
$ ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.20
```

Same result on:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)
$ ld --version
GNU ld version 2.17.50.0.6-14.el5 20061020
```

Runs:

```
$ ./powltest 42    # commented-out sscanf()
5
31
$ ./powltest 42    # commented-out powl()
42
0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you comment out the `sscanf` call, all of the variables have values known at compile time, and the compiler's optimiser is able to determine the result of the `powl` call without actually calling any functions declared in `math.h`.

When you uncomment the `scanf` call, the optimiser is unable to determine at compile-time the result of the `powl` call, so it must call the real `powl` function, which is in a separate library that you must link in with your program with `-lm`.

Comment: Good explanation of why commenting out `sscanf` works when optimisations are enabled in the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Linking with the math library (`-lm`) removes the `undefined reference to 'powl'` error:

```
gcc -o test test.c -lm
```

This is also stated in the man pages for `powl`:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <math.h>
>
> double pow(double x, double y);
> float powf(float x, float y);
> long double powl(long double x, long double y);
> ```
>
> **Link with -lm.**

**EDIT:** It only compiles for me when `sscanf` is commented out if it's also compiled with optimisations (`-OX`), [dreamlax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10320/dreamlax) has the reason in his answer.

Comment: This doesn't explain the other phenomenon where it compiles and works correctly without the `sscanf` call.

Comment: @dreamlax excellent point - I did not read question in detail - nice find.

Comment: @dreamlax: Yeah good point, I didn't look at the question that way - as to why it is that it'll sometimes compile - but instead how to fix the problem from happening.

Comment: Recommendation: libraries should follow object files on the (linker) command line.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I might've heard something like that before, why exactly is that?

Comment: With static libraries, the libraries are scanned on the command line in sequence, and only object files that satisfy an unsatisfied reference are taken from the library. Therefore, with static linking, it is crucial that libraries follow the object files that reference the libraries. Shared libraries are different, and some linkers will scan libraries as they are listed and ensure they are loaded at runtime, but this can lead to the dynamic loader loading libraries that aren't really needed. Sometimes, the linker won't pull in symbols from shared libraries listed before the object files.